# Dividing tasks among pthreads in C?

Tags: c, pthreads

Currently I am making a program that creates 60 random integers from 1-99 and stores them in a [5][12] 2d array, and I'm trying to use pthreads so that a user inputs a number x between 2 & 4 inclusive, and for every even number in the array the number is incremented by 1, and for every odd number it's decremented by 1, with the x number of threads doing the incrementing/decrementing.   Currently I have this:

```
int randint[5][12];
int x;

void *routine(void* arg){
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++){
        if(randint[i][j] % 2){
            randint[i][j]--;
        }
        else randint[i][j]++;
    }
  }
return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   x = atoi(argv[1]);
   time_t t;
   assert(x >= 2 && x <= 4);
   printf("You entered: %d\n", x);

   srand((unsigned) time(&t));
   printf("Original Array\n");
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++){
           randint[i][j] = rand() % (99 + 1 - 1) + 1;
           printf("%d\t", randint[i][j]);
       }
    printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n\n");

   pthread_t thr;
   int r;
   for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++){
       r=pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &routine, (void*)(long)i);
   }
   pthread_join(thr, NULL);



   printf("Updated Array\n");
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++){
           printf("%d\t", randint[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n");


}
```

Currently the pthread function would get weird if there was more than one thread created, which obviously isn't the plan.

My question is how do I divide the [5][12] array up between the x amount of pthreads, so that they don't increment/decrement over each other, and each thread gets a (relatively) equal share of the array?

Comment: If you had 5 threads how would you do it?

Comment: Also, you create `x` threads each using the same `thr` variable. And you only wait for the last one to finish.